# Social media icons do not show in Gmail (html)

Tags: html, templates, gmail, icons

I have a template for a newsletter and in there I have added the following for Social media icons. These social media icons appear in template example nicely, but the moment I send out the newsletter to my Gmail the social media icons are not visible (though if I hover over the spot where they should be visible I do see that they are there because of the links I have added.

Any help is appreciated. Learning the whole html stuff:)

See below the part of the code I added (found online). Also It was mentioned to add the following line in the header of template

```
(<head>)
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></link>
```

---

```
                <tr>
                   <td> <!-- Add font awesome icons -->
<a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook" style="padding-right: 5px; font-size: 17px; "></a><a href="https://twitter.com/albertheijn" class="fa fa-twitter"  style="padding-right: 5px; font-size: 17px;"></a><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/albertheijn" class="fa fa-youtube" style="padding-right: 5px; font-size: 17px;"></a><a href="https://www.instagram.com/albertheijn/?hl=nl" class="fa fa-instagram" style="padding-right: 5px; font-size: 17px; "></a><a href="https://nl.pinterest.com/allerhande/" class="fa fa-pinterest" style="font-size: 17px;"></a></td>
<td style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; text-align: right;">
\[\[CURRENTDATE\]\]</td>
                </tr>
```

[once sent to gmail it does not show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnoXK.jpg)

[template example shows icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSpYi.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Font awesome lib is not working in newsletters or email template. I would suggest you can use images for all these icons. you can find easily them from the following websites:

**1. Flaticon
2. Iconfinder**

This will definitely solve your problem.

Comment: where in the code should I add the images and how should I put that in html language?

Comment: Use following code:
<tr>
<td><img src="image/facebook.png" alt="facebook"></td>
<td><img src="image/facebook.png" alt="facebook"></td>
<td><img src="image/facebook.png" alt="facebook"></td>
</tr>
You can download images form mentioned websites.

Comment: Great thanks a bunch. If I want to also add a hyperlink where should I add. I tried the following: <td href="https://www.facebook.com" style="padding-right: 5px; font-size: 17px; "><img src="image/facebook.png" alt="facebook"/></td>

Comment: <tr>
 <td>
  <a href=""facebook.com" style="padding-right:10px"><img src="image/facebook.png" alt="facebook"></a>
  <a href=""facebook.com" style="padding-right:10px"><img src="image/facebook.png" alt="facebook"></a>
  <a href=""facebook.com" style="padding-right:10px"><img src="image/facebook.png" alt="facebook"></a>
 </td>
</tr>

Comment: you dude is a hero:) Thank you.

Comment: Accepting an answer I do not see the option as it is described in Stackoverflow q&a. Probably because of the privilage that i do not have. Anyways I accept your answer for most useful. Thanks.